# Pygame click to change color of multiple rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

When I click on one rectangle, the color changes. But I can't get the rectangles around it to change at the same time. How can I access the x and y of the rectangles around the one I've clicked?

```
import pygame
import sys

width = 600
height = 600
size = 120
white = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# create list with all rects
all_rects = []
for y in range(0, width, height):
    row = []
    for x in range(0, width, height):
        rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, size-1, size-1)
        row.append([rect, (0, 255, 0)])            
    all_rects.append(row)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # check which rect was clicked and change its color on list
            for row in all_rects:
                for item in row:
                    rect, color = item
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        if color == (0, 255, 0):
                            item[1] = (255, 0, 0)
                        else:
                            item[1] = (0, 255, 0)

    # draw all in every loop

    screen.fill(white)

    for row in all_rects:
        for item in row:
            rect, color = item
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Your rectangles are of known sizes, right?  You do the arithmetic from the current point.  Please reduce your code to *only* what you need to support your question.  See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You should modify lines 15, 17 like this;

```
for y in range(0, width, size):
    row = []
    for x in range(0, width, size):
```

In your current code, all_rects includes only 1 rect.

The full code:

```
import pygame
import sys

width = 600
height = 600
size = 120
white = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# create list with all rects
all_rects = []
for y in range(0, width, size):
    row = []
    for x in range(0, width, size):
        rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, size-1, size-1)
        row.append([rect, (0, 255, 0)])
    all_rects.append(row)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # check which rect was clicked and change its color on list
            for row in all_rects:
                for item in row:
                    rect, color = item
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        if color == (0, 255, 0):
                            item[1] = (255, 0, 0)
                        else:
                            item[1] = (0, 255, 0)

    # draw all in every loop

    screen.fill(white)

    for row in all_rects:
        for item in row:
            rect, color = item
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot I messed around with the code before. I originally had it like you said, but I wanted to change the color of the rectangles within and around the mouse pos when clicks. Sorry for the mistake.